# Docurl display in Doc Preview option SharePoint library

Tags: 2013, document, preview

When the Document ID service is enabled in SP2013 . The "Document preview" popup when hovered still shows the actual url of the document  . How can it be changed to show the docurl instead ?

Answer (score 0):

This may take up to 24 hours for the reset to take effect as a timer job will be scheduled to assign ids to documents already in the site collection.

Also, check How to reset all Document IDs.

- Go to site settings of site collection> Document ID settings.
- Click Reset all Document IDs in this Site Collection to begin with these characters > OK.

You can also apply the above `Reset Operation` and `Run Now` the following Timer Job from Central Administration to don't wait for 24 Hours.

- Document ID enable/disable job
- Document ID assignment job

The Doc ID now has been shown at **View Properties Page**.

[image]

**[Update]**

I'm sorry I read it as **`view`** not **`preview`** , regarding your question, unfortunately, you can't change the `actual URL` to `/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=QASSAS-1-4` because it's generated from `DirName` and `Leaf Name` of its record in [AllDocs] table in Content Database.

Comment: u tired this option ? and does it give you docurl in preview ?

Comment: I am so sorry I read it as view not preview that I think you talk about  view properties I also updated my answer,